# Need to restart IIS to get the sql connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis

I have a webservice running on IIS, which contains the class to connect to the SQL server. Most of the time, we are able to connect the SQL server using the below code. But some time we could not connect the sql server. We are not getting any error. Here is the source code:

```
 public SqlConnection DbConnectSql()
    {
        string str = "Server=xxxx\xxx;database=production;Timeout=60000;user id=sa;password=888*;";

        _con = new SqlConnection(str);

        if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _con.Close();

        _con.Open();

        return _con;
    }
```

We are not getting any response during the execution of  `_con.Open();`. We could not understand why we are not getting any response. I have to restart the IIS every 2 days to open the SQL connection. Can anyone let me know the why I have to restart the IIS to work  `_con.Open();` method?

Comment: Did you checked the Windows logs? If not, you should have look at: https://sqlserver-help.com/2011/06/26/help-where-is-sql-server-errorlog/. It seems to be a SQL Server issue for my first impression.

Comment: So when you noticed that you couldnot connect to SQL server. Have you seen if App Pool is also stopped ?

Comment: Are you closing all the connections after use of it? From how many places are you calling this function? After use of _con object are you closing it?

Comment: That looks suspiciously like you're *sharing* `SqlConnection` objects (if not, why is `_con` not a local to this method?). That's a really bad plan. You should share connection *strings*, not connection *objects*.

Comment: Given that this code half does/half doesn't share connection objects (use of what appears to be a shared variable that keeps being overwritten with new connection objects), I'd guess that you're leaking connections and the error is a failure to obtain a connection from the connection pool. Why you're not seeing an error isn't obvious from the above code but I wouldn't be surprised to see something swallowing exception objects rather than letting the propagate so that you can see them.

Comment: @D Mayuri, I am not using _con object directly from anywhere in the project. I just declared the object above the method. I am accessing the _con object only through the DbConnectSql() method

Comment: After use of _con object are you closing the connection or not? Why are you keeping connection in open state? Wherever you will need, open at that point, use it and close it after use of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interleaving of two calls to `DbConnectSql` that will a) end up with two threads sharing use of one connection object and b) leaks an open connection object:

```
//Thread 1
public SqlConnection DbConnectSql()
{
    string str = ...;
               _con = new SqlConnection(str);
    if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        _con.Close();
    _con.Open();
                                                //Thread 2
                                                public SqlConnection DbConnectSql()
                                                {
                                                    string str = ...;
    //-->Look, thread 2 is overwriting _con-->
                                                             _con = new SqlConnection(str);
    return _con;
}
                                                    if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                                                        _con.Close();
                                                    _con.Open();
                                                     return _con;
                                                }
```

If we're *lucky*, then the first caller won't try to use the connection object before the second caller gets around to calling `Open` on it<sup>1</sup>. But the connection created by the first caller has been opened and now nobody has a reference to it.

You'll be getting errors because the connection pool (eventually) becomes exhausted and so the `Open` call will throw an exception. Why you don't see the exception isn't diagnosable from the code shown.

You're probably being lucky to last 2 days at a time, because these connections *are* eligible for garbage collection and so will *eventually* be returned to the connection pool.

Far better to just share the connection *string* around. Construct `SqlConnection` (and `SqlCommand`) objects in `using` statements that keep them nicely locally scoped and ensures that they are cleaned up neatly. You don't *need* this `DbConnectSql` function. It's doing more harm than good.

---

<sup>1</sup>And there are likely to be other possible errors here, if one caller tries to retrieve a result set whilst the other caller is still retrieving one.

Comment: @combomatrix - I'm trying to show how *two* calls to a single method on separate threads may interleave and lead to leaks and other problems. It's not a formatting issue nor a multiple paste error. I've tried to make that slightly clear but had hoped the top paragraph would already do so.